# Aggregating values based on 2 separate columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a df (partially listed below).

```
    account    company           sum
1    202003         B01        40.50
2    208001         B01    -71596.73
3    280250         B01     -6652.70
4    200001         B13     44362.77
5    202001         B13     13874.25
6    204001         B13      5744.20
7    204102         B13       295.00
8    285091         B13    317145.15
9    286101         B13     11471.13
10   298001         B13    396096.50
```

I am trying to add the numbers in the `df1$sum` column into a new dataframe based on the following criteria:
For each company (`B01` and `B13`) I need to aggregate the column `df1$sum` for all accounts in `df1$accounts` beginning with ^20 and call it `df2$Expenses1` (so in this example that would be `202003` and `208001` for company `B01`).

Separately I need to aggregate all of the accounts beginning with ^28 and ^29 and call it `df2$Expenses2`(so for company `B01` it would only be account `280250` and for company `B13` it would be the sum of accounts `285091`, `286101` and`298001`).

Ultimately, the new data frame `df2` should look something like this:

```
Company   Expenses1   Expenses2
 B01     -71,556.23    -6,652.7
 B13      64,276.22  724,712.78
```

Would really appreciate some help with this!

Comment: What have you tried? We have a nice [R-FAQ on "How to sum by group?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061). The only difference for you is you need to take a subset first - subset the account numbers starting with "20", then sum by group; subset the account numbers starting with "28" or "29", then sum by group.

Comment: If you need help with the "account numbers starting with X" part, I would recommend using the `substr` function to pull the first two digits and test on that. You could also use a regex pattern with `grepl`, something like `"^2[89]"`

Comment: `aggregate(sum ~ company + grepl("^20", account), data=df1, FUN=sum)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(company) %>% 
  summarise(Expenses1 = sum(sum*grepl('^20', account)),
            Expenses2 = sum(sum*grepl('^28|^29', account)))
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   company Expenses1 Expenses2
#   <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 B01        -71556   -  6653
# 2 B13         64276    724713
```

With data table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, lapply(c(Expenses1 = '^20', 
              Expenses2 = '^28|^29'), 
            function(patt) sum(sum*grepl(patt, account)))
   , by = company]

#    company Expenses1 Expenses2
# 1:     B01 -71556.23   -6652.7
# 2:     B13  64276.22  724712.8
```

If you really only have two groups, you can create another grouping variable then use `dcast` or `spread` e.g.

```
df[, .(Expenses = sum(sum))
   , by = .(company, 
            acct_type = paste0('Expenses_', ifelse(grepl('^20', account), '20', 'other')))] %>% 
  dcast(company ~ acct_type)


#    company Expenses_20 Expenses_other
# 1:     B01   -71556.23        -6652.7
# 2:     B13    64276.22       724712.8
```

Comment: I think the first 2 versions will work better as I might have to add more entries to the data frame and group them differently. Nonetheless, thanks for your help